# XSL: Shallow comparison of two xml documents?

Tags: xml, xslt, match

How do I match XML content in XSLT? I'll give you the input XML files and expected output as well as what I've tried:

input1.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
  <list1>
   <value>1</value>
   <value>2</value>
   <value>3</value>
  </list1>
```

input2.xml (edited to show that order should not matter)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
  <list2>
   <value>3</value>
   <value>1</value>
  </list2>
```

desired output (edited to show that order should not matter):

```
1 match
2 no match
3 match
```

Or any permutation thereof.

What I tried:

```
<xsl:variable name="list1" select="document('./resources/input1.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="list2" select="document('./resources/input2.xml')"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$list1/list1/value">
 <xsl:variable name="check"/>
 <xsl:variable name="list1_value" select="."/>
 <xsl:for-each select="$list2/list2/value">
  <xsl:if test="$list1_value=.">
   <xsl:variable name="check" select="1"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$check='1'">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/> match<br />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/> no match<br />
  </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Of course this doesn't work because it tries to use a variable as a variable :)

Additionally, how would you match the larger list to an XSLT applied to a smaller list as such:

XSLT is applied to XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<list2>
 <value>1</value>
 <value>2</value>
</list2>
```

And this list is imported as a variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<list1>
 <value>1</value>
 <value>2</value>
 <value>3</value>
</list1>
```

Same desired result. Thank you!

Comment: I would appreciate a solution using two xml files.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete short and simple solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:doc2>
    <list2>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>2</value>
    </list2>
 </my:doc2>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc2"
      select="document('')/*/my:doc2/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;  ',.,' ')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
   <xsl:if test="not(. = $vDoc2/*[position()=$vPos])">
    <xsl:text>no </xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:text>match</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the first provided XML document:**

```
<list1>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>2</value>
    <value>3</value>
</list1>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
  1 match
  2 match
  3 no match
```

**Update**: The same transformation, but with two different XML files:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pDoc1" select="'/temp/list1.xml'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pDoc2" select="'/temp/list2.xml'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc1"
      select="document($pDoc1)/*"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDoc2"
      select="document($pDoc2)/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDoc1/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;  ',.,' ')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
   <xsl:if test="not(. = $vDoc2/*[position()=$vPos])">
    <xsl:text>no </xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:text>match</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update2**: The OP additionally wants a solution when the shorter lists of elements to compare is the source XML document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:my="my:my">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <my:doc2>
      <list2>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>2</value>
        <value>3</value>
      </list2>
    </my:doc2>

    <xsl:variable name="vDoc1" select="/*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vDoc2"
      select="document('')/*/my:doc2/*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDoc2/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;  ',.,' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(. = $vDoc1/*[position()=$vPos])">
            <xsl:text>no </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>match</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this source XML document**:

```
<list1>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>2</value>
</list1>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
  1 match
  2 match
  3 no match
```

**Update3**: Now a third modification by the OP: The order of elements in the two lists do not matter...

The solution is even simpler:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:my="my:my">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <my:doc2>
      <list2>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>2</value>
        <value>3</value>
      </list2>
    </my:doc2>

    <xsl:variable name="vDoc1" select="/*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vDoc2"
      select="document('')/*/my:doc2/*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDoc2/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;  ',.,' ')"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(. = $vDoc1/*)">
            <xsl:text>no </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>match</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In the case when the XSLT is applied to the smaller list. Let me type it out in a new post.. hold on.

Comment: @Dimitre: You are lightning fast. Wow.

Comment: My additional question is now at the bottom of the original question. Thanks!

Comment: @Dimitre: This will only work if the lists are in order, right? What happens when a list is not in order?

Comment: @Tom: Added the solution to your second question.

Comment: @Tom: What do you mean by: "when the lists are not in order"? It seems that you are asking many more than just one question!!!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I realize now that your original answer requires that the lists are in order. However, I am looking for a solution where order does not matter. I.e. if you have [3,1] and [1,2,3] then 1 matches, 2 does not match, 3 matches. I corrected the original xml lists above. Thank you!

Comment: @Tom: I just answered your *4th* question -- will stop answering any other modifications of your original question. It is high time for you to accept this answer and if you need to -- you are welcome to ask *new* questions.

Comment: Well, shoot, don't get mad. I really think this is valuable now with a solution that doesn't require the lists to be in order. Thanks, you taught me a lot!

Comment: @Tom: I think that you should consider that this is not an assistance site but a Q&A knowledge base. If your question grows to much it will not help anybody else.

Comment: @Alejandro: I'm not sure what you mean. The purpose of clarifying the unordered requirement was to make the solution more general to help more people. If you look closely at Dimitre's first few solutions using position(), you will see how this will not work for all but a very few scenarios of ordered matching lists.